# Функция recv с сокетом в неблокирующем режиме работы

Tags: c++, c, сокет, клиент-сервер, клиент

Сокет, полученный функцией accept был переведен в неблокирующий режим работы функцией `set_non_block_mode(socket[i])`.Когда писал клиент,посылал 4 байта, переведенные в сетевой порядок , а потом и в строку

```
number_of_message2_to_send=htonl(number_of_message2);
memcpy(nmsg,&number_of_message2_to_send,4);
send(s,nmsg,4,MSG_NOSIGNAL);
```

Сейчас сервером пытаюсь получить это сообщение:

```
char some_msg[5] = "\0";
rcv =  recv(sockets[i], some_msg, sizeof(some_msg), 0);
```

Но в отладчике не вижу ничего записанного в строку `some_msg`.

```
int set_non_block_mode(int s)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
unsigned long mode = 1;
return ioctlsocket(s, FIONBIO, &mode);
#else
int fl = fcntl(s, F_GETFL, 0);
return fcntl(s, F_SETFL, fl | O_NONBLOCK);
#endif
}
```

Это функция для перевода в неблокирующий режим

И ещё один вопрос: как убедиться, что сокет действительно переведен в неблокирующий режим работы?

Comment: Конкретно в случае с вопросом, ОС какая?

Comment: @avp, windows 10

Comment: В любом случае, `rcv = recv(...)`, что возвращает?

Comment: @avp, проверил еще раз , вижу ноль , просто отладчик почему-то не реагировал на брэйк-поинты

Comment: Или нет пока данных. В \*nix-ах смотрим errno (в винде не знаю, работает ли с сокетом)  С неблокирующим сокетом лучше обращаться к данным, когда select или poll скажет, что они уже пришли

Comment: 0 это сокет закрыли (по крайней мере в \*nix)

Comment: @avp, да, для этого и использую бесконечный цикл, где внутри селект как условие. Сокет закрыли ? то есть close(s) произошел . Но до close ещё далеко. Просто я по брейк-поинтом на своём сервере хожу, отправил send'ом и хочу увидеть результат в отладчике сервера

Comment: Может кто-то обладающий опытом отладки в винде подтянется. У меня от нее остались впечатления, что все время что-то не так работает

Comment: send у вас точно отправляет данные? приведите полный минимальный код передатчика и приёмника. для винды ошибку сокетов можно посмотреть WSAGetLastError()  если там 0 (при рсв = 0), то соединение было "правильно" закрыто со стороны передатчика.

Comment: на неблокирующем сокете у вас должны валить ошибки WSAEWOULDBLOCK

Answer (score 0):

Для проверки перевода в неблокирующий режим достаточно проверить результат `ioctlsocket`. Также индикатором неблокирующего режима сокета будет являть ошибка функции `send`, которую нельзя просто так использовать с неблокирующим сокетом, результат который вы игнорируете.

Comment: я поискал и увидел, что эта функция вручную позволяет сделать сокет неблокирующим. А как проверка может быть произведена?

Comment: @Elvin Необходимо сравнить значение, возвращаемое функцией со значением, обозначающим успешное выполнение.